# Applying color to uilabel in interface builder goes to background?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uilabel

I've succesfully changed the font (color,size,type) of a text label (UILabel) on my app. Then I tried to do the same on 2 other labels. But this time the color goes to the background. After looking for what could be the issue I still dont understand. Can you help me ?

Thx for your help,

Stephane

Comment: Can you add some code?  It's hard to say what's going wrong in your code without looking at it ...

Comment: There is no code. This is Interface Builder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interface builder just does that sometimes. It's a glitch. Just change the background back to what you want.

Comment: Two years later, xCode 4.6.2 ... still a glitch